# Is it possible to use OAUTH2 in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-mail, xp-cmdshell

I am using `msdb.sp_senddbmail` procedure to send emails from MS SQL Server but now I need to move to OAUTH2.
I tried to implement separate application and call it from procedures using `xp_cmdshell` but 
there are some limitations like argument character number limit and I can't pass HTML from sql to app easy so I am still trying to find best solution for this.
Is it possible to set somehow `sp_senddbmail` to use OAUTH2?